# Formula to increase every 12th row by a percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a formula to estimate future costs for owning rental property.

One example would be taxes, on average the property taxes are increasing **4%** every year where I live.

So I want to create a formula for this and other similar types on calculations.

All I could find online that is close is this: `=INT((ROW(E4)/12)+144)`

But for every 12 rows it just adds 1 number. I need the result to be multiplied by 4% from the previous row and haven't had any luck figuring it out.

Hopefully someone can help!

Comment: show us some sample data of the first lots of rows, and desired output

Answer (score 2):

To make it compounding put the start value in A1.

In A2 put this:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,12)=0,A1*1.04,A1)
```

And copy down.

[image]

---

If you want to base it on a single cell and compound(similar to @Gary'sStudent)

```
=$A$1*(1.04^INT((ROW()-1)/12))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put your based amount in **A1**.  In **B1** enter:

```
=$A$1*(1+4%*(ROUNDUP(ROW()/12,0)-1))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Every 12 rows, the base amount is increased by a fixed 4% *(non-compounding)*.

Change the percentage to suit your needs.  Change the *"12"* in the formula to change the row repetition factor.  To get the increase to compound, a slightly different formula is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),12) = 0, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())) * 1.04, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))
```

This conditional statement uses the modulus (`MOD`) of the row number to perform a calculation by 1.04 every 12th row. The `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))` bit draws in the value from the cell above, incremented by 1.04 (4%) when the conditional statement is true (i.e. *row mod 12* evaluates to 0).